# Why can't I even rollback old edits when there's another edit pending?

Tags: feature-request, support, edits

I just fixed the formatting in a question. Then, the OP turned the changes back (and added an apology for his formatting, so it probably wasn't intentional). Then, someone with not enough rep started editing as well.

The result is that I can't even rollback my old version, which had proper formatting. Is there any way to get around this? If not, can the editing system please be revised so that users with high rep can always edit, or at least always reject edits without requiring confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. Click on revision history

[image: edit history link]

on the post that is awaiting suggested edit approval and press rollback button whereever you want

Comment: @ChrisF I see no problem when hosting images I show here. Could you explain, why it could be bad?

Comment: Stack Exchange has an agreement with imgur to hold images indefinitely. This guards against the (possibly small) chance of images hosted elsewhere becoming unavailable if that site goes down.

Comment: @ChrisF: Do you have any chrome extension which could capture your screen and upload that image on imgur?

Comment: I use the Windows 7 snipping tool to capture the bit of the screen I need, annotate it and then save to disk. I then upload that image. Two steps, but it's not too onerous.

Comment: @genesis-φ - There's no extension that I'm aware of, but [Ctrl]-[G] in the editor will start the uploader, which allows you to upload an image from your hard drive or from another website.  Please don't use the generic imgur.com uploader.

Comment: @ChrisF: my extension requires 2 clicks to get link.. That's the reason I use it